# Lifetime and/or age Info not working?

Tags: materials, node-editor, particles, eevee-render-engine

So, I was trying the particle system in Blender 2.8 for the first time and made a simple changing color depending on the age of the particle.

After many many tweaks, the color still doesn't change.

I would like to know if the Particle Info node isn't working properly or am I just making a mistake.

I'll leave a screenshot of the nodes I'm using and the (wrong) output I'm having.

[image]

Thanks in regard!

Comment: I upvoted, but voted to close as unclear what you're asking. The exact same node setup [works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81fCF.png). Perhaps your lifetime is to large to view the change? Are you in rendered view mode? Are you using cycles (I added the tag)? ***The ParticleInfo node [doesn't work with EEVEE](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/input/particle_info.html?#particle-info-node).***

Comment: @Leander Shouldn't it turn blue in the end? Because the higher particles are close to the end of their lifetime.
The lifetime I choose was 20

Comment: Yes, please look at the image I posted in my first comment (the first link). I replicated the exact same nodes which you have and got the desired result.

Comment: @Leander I see the results in your set of nodes is the desired one, but, if I'm not mistaken, this was replicated in a version prior to 2.8.
I might be doing something wrong but in my file, the output is constantly green.
The question was "if the Particle Info node isn't working in Blender 2.8" because of this particular incorrect result, that in other version would work (2.79 as reference).
Hope I explained myself in a clear way

Comment: It is the same in 2.8. Check the [blend-file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6217/), you can open it in 2.79 and 2.8. The particle node works in 2.8 but ***only with cycles***.

Comment: @Leander Apparently, from time to time and file to file it works.
Your file worked, I created a new one and it worked but in the original still hasn't worked. And it's out of nowhere that it does. So, not sure what conclusion I should get

Comment: Upload your file [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Then others can check it.

Comment: @Leander No, actually I got it. The render engine was Eevee instead of cycles.
When I read your comment I thought you were refering to the display in the viewport, but now I get it.
Sorry to bother and thanks for the explanation and the time you took to help me

Comment: I added "EEVEE" to your tags and added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particle info node does not work with EEVEE.

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/input/particle_info.html?#particle-info-node)

> Particle Info Node
>   **`Cycles Only`**

Switch to the Cycles Render Engine and your node setup will give the expected result.

[image: cycles nodes]